# If $\omega := e^1 \wedge e^2 + e^3 \wedge e^4$, then $\omega \wedge \omega = 2 e^1 \wedge e^2 \wedge e^3 \wedge e^4$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

> I saw the following in the lecture: Fix a dual basis $(e^i)_i$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then for $\omega := e^1 \wedge e^2 + e^3 \wedge e^4 $ holds $\omega \wedge \omega = 2 e^1 \wedge e^2 \wedge e^3 \wedge e^4$.

I realise that this is probably easy to see, but I do not understand why  $\omega \wedge \omega = 2 e^1 \wedge e^2 \wedge e^3 \wedge e^4$. I know the definition of altering multilinear forms and we defined the wedge product as

$$\omega \wedge \eta := \frac{(p+q)!}{p!q!}Alt(\omega \otimes \eta)$$

for $\omega \wedge^p V^*$ and $\eta \wedge^q V^*$, where

$$Alt(\omega) := \frac{1}{p!} \sum_{S_p} sgn(\sigma) \omega^\sigma.$$

Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: Probably easier to just use properties of the wedge product itself. So for example, expand $(e^1 \wedge e^2 + e^3 \wedge e^4) \wedge (e^1 \wedge e^2 + e^3 \wedge e^4) = e^1 \wedge e^2 \wedge e^1 \wedge e^2 + e^3 \wedge e^4 \wedge e^1 \wedge e^2 + e^1 \wedge e^1 \wedge e^2 \wedge e^3 \wedge e^4 + e^3 \wedge e^4 \wedge e^3 \wedge e^4)$ and use anticommutativity $(e^1 \wedge e^2 = -e^2 \wedge e^1)$ and the fact that for any basis vector $e^i \wedge e^i = 0$

Comment: $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$, but anything wedge with itself is zero so $a^2, b^2$ are zero.

Comment: @DavidLui this is not true in general: this example shows that $\omega\wedge \omega \neq 0$! This is true for objects with odd degree

Comment: @Didier You're right,  I meant to say any of the $e_i$'s wedge itself is zero .